# How to call this particular api with it's specific array index through ajax

Tags: ajax, curl

url: https://api.justswap.io/v1/tradepairlist
and i need price of 0_TWNyUwaWjpUyhMAght9sJrTQ9DTdy9o9Jx

here is how i got the output using curl. But sometime it works sometime it doesn't, when it doesn't work it gives error (Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\convertor\api\getinfo1.php on line 25)

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.justswap.io/v1/tradepairlist",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);


$response = json_decode($response, true); //because of true, it's in an array

$value1 = $response['0_TWNyUwaWjpUyhMAght9sJrTQ9DTdy9o9Jx']['price'];
echo "Live price of BXB: ". $value1 ."<br/>";
```

Comment: well, you can't ask the api to get the specific data in the list unless there's any end-point the api provider has defined.
So what you can do is fetch all the data and then filter out the one you want

Comment: yes but already have done it using curl but i want to do it with ajax, because some time that api is working some it is not.

Comment: Yeah, this can be done with ajax. You just have to set the method to 'GET'.How far have you written your code? Please share for clarity

Comment: Thank you @SrinathKamath for your attention to our problem, it was api problem in localhost, it is working on cpanel when we tested, Thank you

Comment: Cool  Great job

Answer (score 0):

Above curl code is working fine for calling api on live server, it was localhost problem